How to change the axis orientation of the cylinder in `ContourPlot3D`?
How to get the axis of the cylinder oriented along the red line shown in the figure below ?
Here is my code :
Show[ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full], 
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, InfiniteLine[{{-20, -10, 0}, {20, 10, 0}}]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]


Thank you in advance.

By rotating it?

Try: Graphics3D[  GeometricTransformation[   Cylinder[{{-20, 0, 0}, {20, 0, 0}}, Sqrt[10]],    RotationTransform[Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]]]

Can't it be done in ContourPlot3D, without using Cylinder ?

The surface (x-2y)^2/9 + z^2 == 10 looks about right.

@LouisB Should be (x - 2 y)^2/5 + z^2 == 10 since we need to use rotationmatrix {{-(2/Sqrt[5]), 1/Sqrt[5], 0}, {-(1/Sqrt[5]), -(2/Sqrt[5]), 0}, {0, 0,    1}}.

@cvgmt Yeah, I put 5 in the denominator first, but the graphic just didn't look right when I looked down the axis.

@LouisB  Show[ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10,     10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50,    MaxRecursion -> 4],   ContourPlot3D[(x - 2  y)^2/5 + z^2 == 10, {x, y, z} ∈     RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, {-20, -10, 0} - {20, 10, 0}}, {0, 0,        0}]@Cuboid[{-20, -10, -10}, {20, 10, 10}], Mesh -> None,    PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4], PlotRange -> All,   BoxRatios -> Automatic]  we can see that  (x - 2 y)^2/5 + z^2 == 10 is right.

@cvgmt  Nice trick using the Cuboid as a reference shape.  Thanks!

Given the cylinder( y^2 + z^2 == 10 ) we can find its axis as
axis = InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}];

Red line
line = InfiniteLine[{{-20, -10, 0}, {20, 10, 0}}];

The two lines are lying in the same plane(xy), therefore a rotation in xy plane would suffice in order to align the cylinder's axis with the red line.
Calculating the angle between the axis and the line:
axisVector = First@*Differences @@ axis; (* {1, 0, 0} *)
lineVector = First@*Differences @@ line; (* {40, 20, 0} *)

angle = VectorAngle[axisVector, lineVector] (* ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]] *)

Plotting:
plot = ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}
        , Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], First@plot
  , GeometricTransformation[First@plot, RotationTransform[ArcCos[2/Sqrt[5]], {0, 0, 1}]]
  , Opacity[.7], Thick, Blue, axis, Thick, Red, line}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]



Besides of rotate the original contourplot3d, we also have aother ways to get the desired results.
Method-1

We set the DisplayFunction to be

ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> 
  RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, dir}, center]@{x, y, z}]

to rotate the original contourplot3d.
Clear["Global`*"];
dir = {-20, -10, 0} - {20, 10, 0};
{cylinder1, cylinder2} = 
  ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 
      10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
     DisplayFunction -> #] & /@ {Identity, 
    ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> 
      RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, dir}] . {x, y, z}]};
Show[cylinder1, cylinder2, BoxRatios -> Automatic]


Method-2

Using the RegionDistance respect to the InfiniteLine[{{-20, -10, 0}, {20, 10, 0}}] to define a new ContourPlot3D.


Clear["Global`*"];
line = InfiniteLine[{{-20, -10, 0}, {20, 10, 0}}];
dir = {-20, -10, 0} - {20, 10, 0};
center = {0, 0, 0};
dist = RegionDistance[line];
cylinder1 = 
  ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 
    10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All];
cylinder2 = 
  ContourPlot3D[
   dist@{x, y, z} == Sqrt[10], {x, y, z} ∈ 
    RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 0}, dir}, center]@
     Cuboid[{-20, -10, -10}, {20, 10, 10}], 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None];
Show[cylinder1, cylinder2, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic]


Method-3

We define a cylinder with center,direction,radius and length.

cylinder[center_, dir_, radius_, length_] := 
 Module[{bases}, 
  bases = Select[
    Orthogonalize@Normal@HodgeDual[dir], # =!= {0, 0, 0} &];
  ParametricPlot3D[
   center + radius {Cos[t], Sin[t]} . bases + s*Normalize[dir], {t, 0,
     2  π}, {s, -length/2, length/2}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All]]


Show[cylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, Sqrt[10], 40], 
 cylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {-20, -10, 0} - {20, 10, 0}, Sqrt[10], 40], 
 cylinder[{10, 20, 30}, {1, 1, 1}, Sqrt[10], 40], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]



Use the equation for the distance between a line and a point in 3D space:
x1 = {-20, -10, 0};
x2 = {20, 10, 0};
x0 = {x, y, z};
d = Sqrt[10];
neweqn = Simplify[Norm[Cross[x0 - x1, x0 - x2]]^2 - d^2 Norm[x2 - x1]^2, 
    Assumptions -> Element[x | y | z, Reals]]

(* 400 (-50 + x^2 - 4 x y + 4 y^2 + 5 z^2) *)

Show[ContourPlot3D[{y^2 + z^2 == 10, neweqn == 0}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full], 
 Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, InfiniteLine[{{-20, -10, 0}, {20, 10, 0}}]}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]


Explanation:  the quantity neweqn is equal to $$[(\vec{x}_0 - \vec{x}_1) \times (\vec{x}_0 - \vec{x}_2)]^2 - d^2 (\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_2)^2.$$  According to the derivation given in the link above, all points with a distance of $d = \sqrt{10}$ from the given line will satisfy the equation neweqn == 0;  so this equation defines a 3D cylinder with the same radius centered on this new axis.
